# Min-max normalization of individual columns in a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, normalization

I have a dataset which has 4 columns/attributes and 150 rows.  I want to normalize this data using min-max normalization.  So far, my code is:

```
minData=min(min(data1))
maxData=max(max(data1))
minmaxeddata=((data1-minData)./(maxData))
```

Here, `minData` and `maxData` returns the global minimum and maximum values.  Therefore, this code actually applies a min-max normalization over all values in the 2D matrix so that the global minimum is 0 and the global maximum is 1.

However, I would like to perform the same operation on each **column** individually.  Specifically, each column of the 2D matrix should be min-max normalized independently from the other columns.

I tried using just using `min(data1)` and `max(data1)`, but got the error saying that the **Matrix dimensions must agree**.

However, by using the global minimum and maximum, I got the values in the range of `[0-1]` and have done experimentations using this normalized dataset. I would like to know whether there is any problem in my results?   Is there a problem in my understanding as well?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to normalize each column of `data1`.  Also, as each column is an **independent** data set and most likely having different dynamic ranges, doing a global min-max operation is probably not recommended.  I would recommend that you go with your initial thoughts in normalizing each column individually.

Going with your error, you can't subtract `data1` with `min(data1)` because `min(data1)` would produce a row vector while `data1` is a matrix.  You are subtracting a matrix with a vector which is why you are getting that error.

If you want to achieve what you're asking, use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to broadcast the vector and repeat it for as many rows as you have `data1`.  Therefore:

```
mindata = min(data1);
maxdata = max(data1);
minmaxdata = bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, data1, mindata), maxdata - mindata);
```

With later versions of MATLAB, broadcasting is built-in to the language, so you can simply do:

```
mindata = min(data1);
maxdata = max(data1);
minmaxdata = (data1 - mindata) ./ (maxdata - mindata);
```

It's a lot easier to read and still does the same job.

---

## Example

```
>> data1 = [5 9 9 9 3 3; 3 10 2 1 10 1; 2 4 4 6 5 5]

data1 =

 5     9     9     9     3     3
 3    10     2     1    10     1
 2     4     4     6     5     5
```

When I run the above normalization code, I get:

```
minmaxdata =

    1.0000    0.8333    1.0000    1.0000         0    0.5000
    0.3333    1.0000         0         0    1.0000         0
         0         0    0.2857    0.6250    0.2857    1.0000
```

Comment: @ rayryeng : Your answer was really helpful..and I would like to know how can I modify the same code if my data set  contains values like                                                      

 (8.121287971003636e-12, -0.01595515444407518)


 and I want to get the whole values without being rounded...can u suggest any idea?

Comment: What do you mean "whole values without being rounded"?  What is your expected result?

Comment: I mean I need each and every values in the dataset after normalization as they are..ies  , if values in the dataset are like 8.121287971003636e-12 , I would like to normalize the same and get the normalized values as they are.(ies,not being rounded to some decimal points).hope u got what I mean..

Comment: No I don't.  Sorry.  Can you post a small numerical example?... what the data is, and what you expect it to look like.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - Thanks.  I've been using Python a lot more and the / operator already implicitly does it element-wise.  I forget that MATLAB additionally uses it for matrix division.