# Normalizing vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a series of vectors which I would like to normalize between 0 & 1. So far, I have resampled my data to 10kHz and then removed noise as well as created auxiliary signals to show the change in energy.

My next task is to normalize said vectors and for that I used "normc" but I still cannot get my column values normalized between 0 & 1. What could I do to perform my task?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*. If `normc` doesnt work, shows us why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Min-max normalization of individual columns in a 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404157/min-max-normalization-of-individual-columns-in-a-2d-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about column vectors, and the L2 norm, this should do it:

```
    a = a ./ repmat(sqrt(sum(a.^2)),size(a,1),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`normc` just takes the column vectors and makes them have length 1 in the Euclidean norm. If you're trying to scale the data so that all of the individual values lay between 0 and 1, that's fairly straightforward.

If you have data in the range `[a,b]`, and you want to scale it to the range `[0,1]`, you need to shift by `a` and divide by `(b-a)`.

Call `A` the matrix of column vectors, which has `n` rows and `m` columns. I think the following should work:

```
A_min = repmat(min(A,[],1),n,1);
A_max = repmat(max(A,[],1),n,1);

A_scaled = (A - A_min)./(A_max-A_min);
```

If you want to scale along the columns, you would do:

```
A_min = repmat(min(A,[],2),1,m);
A_max = repmat(max(A,[],2),1,);

A_scaled = (A - A_min)./(A_max-A_min);
```